# Pass python variable from object to parent

Tags: python, variables

I'm writing a python program that wants to keep track of a status flag from several different places.  I've done some reading to discover that a Python variable passed into a function can't necessarily be modified by that function (in my case it can't).  As an example:

```
def testfunc(self, inVariable):
  inVariable = 4

def main():
  myVariable = 6
  print myVariable
  testfunc(myVariable)
  print myVariable
```

In this situation, the output would be:
6
6

and the 4 would never be assigned to myVariable.

Realizing that this cannot be changed, does anyone have a good workaround for this situation?  Global variables, perhaps?

The situation I am dealing with is much more complex than this one, so something like returning a value and assigning it is not an easy option for me.

Thanks!

Marlon

Comment: What's wrong with `def testfunc(): return 4`?

Comment: Could you give us a better idea of what the actual problem is? What does the status refer to, and in what circumstances should it change?

Answer (score 1):

> Global variables, perhaps?

Global variables are almost always a bad idea.

A variable in Python is just binding a name to a value, in `testFunc` all you're doing is changing the value bound to `inVariable` rather than changing the variable itself.

You'll need to pass an object to your function and modify its attributes.  You use a built-in type like `list` or `dict`, but it's just as easy to create your own class:

```
>>> class Status(object):
...     # Lazily use a class variable as a default for instance variables
...     flag = 0
...
>>> def testFunc(status):
...     status.flag = 4
...
>>> s = Status()
>>> s.flag = 6
>>> s.flag
6
>>> testFunc(s)
>>> s.flag
4
```

Comment: Class variables != instance variables.

Comment: This code would work exactly the same with the `flag = 0` line replaced with `pass`.

Comment: I'm using class variables as defaults for instance variables.

Answer (score 1):

Three solutions:

- pass it a collection object containing your data

  ```
  def testFunc1(var):
      var[0] = 4

  myvar = [6]
  testFunc1(myvar)
  print(myvar[0])
  ```
- make the variable a global

  ```
  myvar = None
  def testFunc2():
      global myvar
      myvar = 4

  myvar = 6
  testFunc2()
  print(myvar)
  ```

  I don't generally like global variables, but depending on what you're doing it may make sense.
- return the variable from the function

  ```
  def testFunc3(var):
      return 4

  myvar = 6
  myvar = testFunc3(myvar)
  print(myvar)
  ```

**Edit:** a fourth option; as per your declaration,

```
def testfunc(self, inVariable):
```

this appears to be a class method (passing `self` as an argument). If the status flag is a class variable or instance variable, the method can change it as `self.status = 4` and this change will be retained.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for the good ideas.  I ended up "cheating" on this one: the program is written with Qt so I was able to use signals and slots to accomplish my goal.

Using class variables is an interesting idea; it sort of tricks python into creating a variable that is mutable, correct?  I think global variables may have been a good way to go if not for my alternative solution; this seems like one of the rare cases where they may have been a good idea.

Hopefully these answers will help others with similar problems as well.

Cheers

Marlon